# Vba doesn't forward the latest message in the conversation

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myitems = myInbox.Items

For Each myitem In myitems
    If myitem.Class = olMail Then
        If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Hi") > 0 Then
            If myitem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress = "xyz@abc.com" Then
                With myitem.Forward
                    .Recipients.Add "pqr@abc.com"
                    .CC = "xyz@abc.com"
                    .Body = "Hey,there"
                    .Send
                End With
            End if
        End if
    End if
Next myitem
```

Basically if I got the **last email with subject line** as **"Hi"** from **xyz** then I want to **forward** it to **pqr** and **CC xyz** . Everthing works fine but the forwarded message is not the original one but it just composes a new email. I always want to add something while forwarding an email in addition to what I received from **xyz**. Can anyone help please. Thanks.

Edit:- If I put a display command immediately after **With myitem.Forward** it shows the entire thread but it disappears and turns in to a new email once I add the recipient and the body. Also I think that it can interpret **.body** as the entire new body and I should find something which will add to existing body.

Comment: Do you want to send the latest (per your title) or the original (per your text)? How are you getting `myitem`?

Comment: There may be lots of false positive. What if subject is like "My team scored Very **Hi**gh last week"?

Comment: have you tried `.Body = "Hey,there" & vbNewLine & myitem.Forward`

Comment: @DickKusleika I am looping all the emails in my inbox and that's how get myitem. Thanks.

Comment: @PatricK I used "Hi" to just make it simple, in reality it's much more bigger Subject line. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: Show the loop. You may just be looping in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Om3r That just adds the subject line starting with "FW:" in the email and  does not get the entire body.

Comment: Add to the existing body: `.Body =  "Hey, there" & vbCrLF & .Body`

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks! that works, I tried and found that the format changes in to plain text, do you know if that can be corrected?

Comment: Yes, either using the `HTMLBody` or by getting a handle on the `myitem.Forward.Inspector` which exposes an MS Word-like object which would allow you to manipulate the "rich text" body.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to preserve the existing message you should to insert your text before the existing property value (in case of plain text emails).

```
  .Body = "Hey,there" + .Body
```

Or inject your HTML markup into the `<body>` element to keep the HTML markup well-formed.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to customize the message body.